# Django: How to display an older version of a queryset in template that has been modified in views.py?

Tags: django

I am using [django-notifications](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications) to create an inbox of unread messages in my app. And I have very basic view that queries all the unread messages for a certain recipient and then changes the BooleanField of unread to False that distinguishes them as read:

```
 def inbox(request):
 ...
 newmessages = Notification.objects.filter(recipient=User, unread=True)
 read = User.notifications.mark_all_as_read(recipient=User)
 return render(request, 'myapp/inbox.html', {'newmessages': newmessages})
```

And in my template I just want to display the queryset using `{{newmessages}}`

But in this approach, all that ends up happening is that the newmessages queryset ends up being empty since they all get marked as read. How can I make it so that in my template I display the unread messages for just that single page visit and immediately turn the unread value to False in the backend while my newmessages queryset still holds the unread messages? Basically, I want a way to mark the messages as read after I show the queryset of newmessages to the user, but in my current approach, my queryset is getting emptied out before I can show the unread messages to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache the queryset in a list before marking the messages as read:

```
newmessages = list(Notification.objects.filter(recipient=User, unread=True))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks. Simple problem with a simple answer. Thanks for that.